# Resizing images in Keras ImageDataGenerator flow methods

Tags: image-processing, keras

The Keras `ImageDataGenerator` class provides the two flow methods `flow(X, y)` and `flow_from_directory(directory)` (https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/).

Why is the parameter

> target_size: tuple of integers, default: (256, 256). The dimensions to which all images found will be resized

Only provided by *flow_from_directory(directory)* ? And what is the most concise way to add reshaping of images to the preprocessing pipeline using *flow(X, y)* ?

Comment: I have the same problem -- if I upsample all images before feeding them into the `flow()` method, I run out of memory.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`flow_from_directory(directory)` generates augmented images from directory with arbitrary collection of images. So there is need of parameter `target_size` to make all images of same shape.

While `flow(X, y)` augments images which are already stored in a sequence in X which is nothing but numpy matrix and can be easily preprocessed/resized before passing to `flow`. So no need for `target_size` parameter. As for resizing I prefer using `scipy.misc.imresize` over `PIL.Image resize`,  or cv2.resize as it can operate on numpy image data.

```
import scipy
new_shape = (28,28,3)
X_train_new = np.empty(shape=(X_train.shape[0],)+new_shape)
for idx in xrange(X_train.shape[0]):
    X_train_new[idx] = scipy.misc.imresize(X_train[idx], new_shape)
```

Comment: Condensed it to a oneliner: X_data_resized = [scipy.misc.imresize(image, new_shape) for image in X_data]

Comment: Can be resized before passing to flow? 32 gb memory is easily gets full if I resize all images at once. That’s why we need flow() to resize batch by batch.

Comment: @ozgur ImageDataGenerator accepts preprocessing_function in constructor method. According to the documentation thats what you're need

Answer (score 4):

For large training dataset, performing transformations such as resizing on the entire training data is very memory consuming. As Keras did in ImageDataGenerator, it's better to do it batch by batch. As far as I know, there're 2 ways to achieve this other than operating the whole dataset:

1. You can use [Lambda Layer](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-Lambda-layer-in-Keras) to create a layer and then feed original training data to it. The output is the resized you need.

Here is the sample code if you use TensorFlow as the backend of Keras:

```py
original_dim = (32, 32, 3)
target_size = (64, 64)
input = keras.layers.Input(original_dim)
x = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda image: tf.image.resize(image, target_size))(input)
```

2. As @Retardust mentioned, maybe you can customize your own ImageDataGenerator as well as the preprocessing_function.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else who wants to do this, .flow method of [ImageDataGenerator](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/) does not have a target_shape parameter and we cannot resize an image using preprocessing_function parameter as the documentation states `The function will run after the image is resized and augmented. The function should take one argument: one image (Numpy tensor with rank 3), and should output a Numpy tensor with the same shape.`

So in order to use .flow, you will have to pass resized images only otherwise use a custom generator that resizes them on the fly.

Here's a sample of custom generator in keras (can also be made using python generator or any other method)

```
class Custom_Generator(keras.utils.Sequence) :
    def __init__(self,...,datapath, batch_size, ..) :

    def __len__(self) :
        #calculate data len, something like len(train_labels)


    def load_and_preprocess_function(self, label_names, ...):
        #do something...
        #load data for the batch using label names with whatever library

    def __getitem__(self, idx) :
        batch_y = train_labels[idx:idx+batch_size]
        batch_x = self.load_and_preprocess_function()
        return ( batch_x, batch_y )
```

Answer (score 2):

```
X_data_resized = numpy.asarray([skimage.transform.resize(image, new_shape) for image in X_data])
```

because of the above code is now depreciated...

Answer (score 1):

There is also (newer) method `flow_from_dataframe()` which accepts a Pandas dataframe with file paths and y data as columns - and it also allows to specify the target size. Just in case your image data is not organized directory-wise!