# How to resize all images in the dataset before passing to a neural network?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, google-colaboratory, conv-neural-network, vgg-net

I am using colab to build CNN. Input shape to network(vgg16) is (224,224,3), while i have a training dataset(CIFAR10) having 50000 samples of (32,32,3). I tried tf.resize() for a single image it works and perfectly resizes.

```
im = tf.image.resize(x_train[1], [224, 224])
print(im.shape)
#(224, 224, 3)
```

But how can write this as a function which takes x_train(numpy.ndarray) and returns x_train_new of type `numpy.ndarray`, without crashing colab?

However i wrote function like

```
def resize(data):
  result = []
  for im in data:
    result.append(np.resize(im, (224,224, 3)))
  result = np.array([result])
  return np.squeeze(result, axis=0)
```

But the above function keeps crashing as RAM ran out !

Please help !

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: Looks like you are fitting whole array into ram. If that's the case, to reduce ram usage you can use tf.dataset api, data_generators, sequence api etc.

Comment: Have yout tried this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41758385/resizing-images-in-keras-imagedatagenerator-flow-methods
Check the second answer

Answer (score 1):

`tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory` can be used to resize the images from directory.

```
import tensorflow as tf
data_dir ='/content/sample_images' 
image = train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="training",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(224, 224),
  batch_size=batch_size)
```